# Xdebug Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, отладка

Установлен XAMPP. Visual Studio Code. PHP Debug
Не активны кнопки "Step Over", "Step Into", "Step Out".
браузер Google Chrome перезагружаю. Breakpoint установлены.
Отсутствует Path

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path

[image: Configuration File (php.ini) Path]
PHP Version 7.4.16

C:\xampp\php\php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.3-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll" 
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.default_enable=1

settings.json
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"    
}
```